# $http simultaneous duplicate API call, return promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-http-interceptors, angular-cache

In my app, we are using micro services structure, and for that we have aso added caching.

But there is a scenario in which multiple same request gets fired, and the request are fired at the same time, so caching also doesn't seem to work. 
I want that for duplicate request it should send promise of previous request.

Also there are lots of services, so adding promise to each service will not work. Is there any place where to handle duplicate request and pass the previous request promise at a common place. might be by using decorator or http interceptor.

Service call

```
testService.getTestByIds = function (
                                testIds,
                                contextInfo) {
         var params = {
                 testId: requestDefinitionIds
           };
         params = CommonProvider.apppendContextParams(contextInfo, params,testInfoCache);
          return $http.get(SERVICE_URL + 'tests', {
                                cache: testInfoCache,
                                params: params,
                                transformResponse: CommonProvider.appendTransformer($http.defaults.transformResponse, function (value) {
                                    return transformTestResponse(value);
                                })
                            });
                        };
```

Comment: The scenario is pretty brief to answer, is it the case that you have nested API calls? Or is there a race condition? `$q` service might solve at least half of these issues.

Comment: Its kind of race condition. There will be multiple getById call for same id. I can't handle this in controller. So I can change in service or interceptor

Comment: I'd go with decorator, it's the way to wrap the $http service and modify its behavior. Example 1: http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2013/07/31/double-requests/; Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/referee/hh30bh0q/

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro I am not too good with decorators. So I tried to use the 2nd example given in jsfiddle, but it is giving error `Cannot read property 'transformResponse' of undefined`. I have used `transformResponse` in my service.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro I have also added me service code for refrence

Comment: @Anita the author didn't extend the whole http object, only the methods; anyways, I've made an update, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/hh30bh0q/60/

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro using this  jsfiddle.net/hh30bh0q/60, still gives me same error ` Cannot read property 'transformResponse' of undefined`

Comment: @Anita my mistake, I think I must've sent you the wrong link; anyways, I've added the `transformResponse` key to the example. http://jsfiddle.net/hh30bh0q/63/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean caching on the client, you could try something like this:

```
const activeRequest = 
  () => {
    const requests = {};
    return (url,params) => {
      const promise = requests[url+JSON.stringify(params)];
      if(promise){
        return promise;
      }
      return requests[url+JSON.stringify(params)] = 
        //not sure what you use for angular, maybe $http for angular1
        fetch(url,params)
        .then(
          x=>{
            requests[url+JSON.stringify(params)] = undefined;
            return x;
          }
        )
    }
  }
```

Comment: The logic seems correct. but I cant change this in controller. So How can I apply these change to service method

Comment: @Anita Do you call `$http`? Instead of calling $http you can call `activeRequest` (inject as service) and have `activeRequest` call `$http` if needed.